# Quoting directory names in bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, prompt

I want to quote the current directory in my prompt.

Eg, if I do:

```
mkdir $'new\nline'; cd $'new\nline'
```

I want my prompt to display `$'new\nline'`, and NOT print a literal newline.

I'm seeing interesting behaviour trying to print backslashes (`\`) in `bash 5.0.9`:

```
p='\\n'       && echo -E "${p@P}"  # 2 slashes; output = '\n'
p='\\\\n'     && echo -E "${p@P}"  # 4 slashes; output = '\n'
p='\\\\\\n'   && echo -E "${p@P}"  # 6 slashes; output = '\\n'
p='\\\\\\\\n' && echo -E "${p@P}"  # 8 slashes; output = '\\n'
```

Note: [`${parameter@P}` is a string that is the result of expanding the value of `parameter` as if it were a prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Why is the output equivalent with (2 and 4), and (6 and 8) slashes?

Given this confusion, and:

```
mkdir '\\n' && cd '\\n'
```

I couldn't work out how to programatically transform `\\n` into a string such that it was displayed in a prompt either as: `\\\\n` or `$'\\\\n'`, as well as handling the literal newline case.

---

How do I get directory names quoted in the prompt such that:

- `~` is displayed for `$HOME` and a leading `~/` for subdirectories
- Other paths are escaped only if required
- A copy-paste of the displayed string is a valid shell token referring to the current directory

Eg `"$HOME/dir with spaces"` should be displayed as either:

- `~/dir\ with\ spaces`
- `~/$'dir with spaces'`
- `~/'dir with spaces'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I include `\w` in the prompt, and `cd $'/tmp/new\nline'`, Bash shows just `/tmp/newline` in the prompt. It doesn't seem to print the literal newline, but that's also not an unambiguous output format.

`${var@P}` is meant to expand prompt-style escapes, like `\u` for username, `\h` for hostname and `\w` for the working directory, I doubt you want those here. Instead `${var@Q}`, which quotes the output might be more useful?

Setting `PS1='${PWD@Q}\$ '`, I get the prompt: `$'/tmp/new\nline'$`, or `'/tmp'$` if the path is nicer. An alternative might be `PS1='$(printf "%q" "$PWD")\$ '`, which gives a different quoting in some cases, and e.g. leaves the quotes out in the case of a "nice" path, so `/tmp$`.

---

To get the home directory shown as a tilde, one option would be to do that replacement manually:

```
set_ppath() {
    printf -v ppath "%q" "$PWD"
    ppath="${ppath/$HOME/"~"}";
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_ppath
PS1='$ppath\$ '
```

It still quotes the *whole* path if a part of it needs quoting, though. To work around that, I suppose you'd have to walk the path piece by piece.

---

I have no idea why `${var@P}` collapses the backslashes like that, though.

Comment: Cheers! I wanted to add coloured `/` in my prompt's `$PWD`, so I came up with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543621/143394).

Answer (score 0):

Based on ilkkachu's answer, I came up with:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=_prompt_bash_set

_prompt_bash_set() {
  # Working directory
  local prefix=''  # Used to contain '~' if $PWD directory is under $HOME
  local dir=$PWD

  # Replace leading $HOME with ~ if at beginning of string
  case "$PWD"/ in # Extra slash at end prevents substring match
    "$HOME"/)  # $PWD == $HOME itself
      prefix=\~  # no trailing /
      dir='' ;;
    "$HOME"/?*)  # $PWD is a subdir of $HOME
      prefix=\~/  # Add trailing / so that possibly quoted string goes after ~/ for path validity
      dir=${PWD#$HOME/} ;;   # Remove $HOME and / as this is now in $prefix
  esac

  if [[ $PWD != $HOME ]]; then  # $PWD != $HOME
    # Avoid ${PWD@Q} as it produced a literal \n inside $''
    printf -v dir '%q' "$dir"  # Quote directory minus $HOME

    # Replace a single slash with 4!?! slashes
    # https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/543473/143394
    dir=${dir//\\/\\\\\\\\}

    # Prevent command and variable substitution:
    dir=${dir//\`/\\\`}  # escape ` as \`
    dir=${dir//\$/\\\$}  # escape $ as \$
  fi

  PS1='\u@\h:'$dir'\$ '
}
```

This has the quoted directory as literal text in `$PS1` rather than inclusion via a variable.

The advantage of doing it this way is that I can then go on to [colour slashes in the directory](https://superuser.com/q/49092/365890) which my eyes find easier to parse.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `printf %q` isn't POSIX either, but it's more widely supported than Bash's `${var@Q}`. On the other hand, `PROMPT_COMMAND` might be Bash-only too.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks, I've updated the comment accordingly :)